# Android: diagnosing source of app's excessive battery drain with battery historian

Tags: android, performance, profiling, battery, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to identify why my alarm clock app's "app usage" under my battery settings is so high (~10%) with very light use given the fact that the app's "device usage" is only 1% (running on android 8.0). This is my first time using battery historian and was hoping for help identifying any red flags in the app stats for my app that could account for this discrepancy (super high app usage and low device usage battery stats).

[app stats part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlOnr.png)

[app stats part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7F3z.png)

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have any confirmation that this is a bug, the moment I released the app, everything was normal. The battery reporting on my pixel running Android 8.0 was likely the problem.